# Error importing modules from gdata

Tags: python, gdata, importerror, google-api-python-client

I'm using virtualenv with my application, and I've installed gdata, jira, and gspread using `env/bin/pip install <lib name>` in terminal under my project folder. I'm following the documentation from the Google API but it is not working?

In the documentation, in order to do error handling you need to do:
`from gdata import errors`

And in order to create an instance of the Drive API service (in order to later on create a file) you need to do:
`from gdata.discovery import build`

However the files are different, there is no "discovery" or "errors" and when I run `env/bin/python run.py` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from gdata import errors
ImportError: cannot import name errors
```

(same with discovery)

I thought that maybe they mean `from apiclient import errors` literally in the documentation, so I tried pip installing apiclient and replacing gdata with apiclient but it still does not work.

I downloaded the gdata.zip file and unzipped it and looked through the sample code (especially for spreadsheet since that's what I'm trying to create) and they take a very different approach than the documentation and I'm very confused. My goal is to use their API to just create a spreadsheet from the code, but I do not plan on using their API to edit the spreadsheet itself, I plan on using gspread ([Github](https://github.com/burnash/gspread)).

I've done a lot of research and I've been directed to a lot of different places and I might have perhaps mixed up the code? Does anyone know what I did wrong/have a fix? A huge thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of import error is usually caused by the user installing another module of the same name. Do you by any chance have a `gdata.py` somehwere on your Python path?

You can verify whether this is causing the issue by:

```
import gdata
print gdata.__file__
```

This tells you where the interpreter is loading the code from.

Comment: I saw a similar post where their actual file was gdata.py but I thought I was in the clear since I never made a file like that, but I also didn't know how to check (thank you for showing me!) and something may have gone wrong? I just ran that code and I got `/home/dj/DailyReport/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/__init__.pyc` but I'm not really sure what that means. Should I delete that file? (I probably should mention that for some reason i have 2 of every file, one is .py and the other .pyc, but I'm not sure why or what that is for)

Comment: The .pyc files are just an optimization: when the interpreter imports a module it checks for both a .py AND a .pyc. If it only finds a .py, or if the .py is newer than the .pyc, it will attempt to create a new .pyc file which is the compiled module.

In this case it does look as though you are importing the gdata module as installed by something like `pip` in a virtual environment, so it looks like my guess may be wrong, sorry.

Comment: Oh, ok! Thank you for explaining. Yeah it's acting a little weird. I think their documentation is old? I found a different way to do it and it is working for now. Instead of discovery I use gdata.docs.client in order to create a spreadsheet. I think certain parts of their documentation is not up to date with the newer gdata. Either way, I appreciate your help! Thanks again.